# Zabbix escalation: notify every XX period of time

Tags: zabbix

Hello experts!
According to **zabbix v2.2** help: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation...on/escalations if I configure zabbix escalation as follows:
Step duration : 18000
1 - 0   Send message to user groups: Alert level 1 via all media Immediately    Default 
2   Send message to user groups: Alert level 2 via all media 00:30:00   Default 
3   Send message to user groups: Alert level 3 via all media 01:00:00   Default

I expect 1 notification immediately from zabbix to "Alert level 1", after 30 min ( 00:30:00) second notification to "Alert level 2" and after next 30 min (01:00:00) notification to "Alert level 3" group.

Instead of this scenario zabbix sends notifications to "Alert level 1" every one minute.
Could you please advise what is wrong.
Thank you!

Comment: A screenshot of operation configuration would be very welcome - raw text is hard to parse.

Comment: Double question: https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=48171